# How do I store files to another location outside of Laravel 5.5 file structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ftp

I am developing an application using `Laravel 5.5` and currently uploading files in the `public/storage` directory using the symlink command.

The application is hosted on a server which is part of my organization's domain/network.

What I would like to do is to save my files on another server already dedicated to file storage so as to ease up traffic on the application server.

I have created an `FTP` configuration in the `disks` array of `config/filesystems.php` as I saw in other examples but when the upload is executed I get

> Could not connect to host: xx.xx.xx.xx on port 21.

Below is the FTP config I added.

```php
'ftp' => [
    'driver' => 'ftp',
    'host' => env('FTP_HOST'),
    'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
    'root' => '/file_storage',
    'passive' => false,
    'port' => 21,
],
```

In my `.env` file, this is what I have

```
FTP_HOST=10.13.1.66
FTP_USERNAME=agriculture\foo
FTP_PASSWORD=bar
```

The code in the controller that calls the FTP array:

```php
$file = $request->nid_file;
$doc = $individual->id . '_NIDScan_' . md5($file->getClientOriginalName()) . '.' . $file->extension();
Storage::disk('ftp')->put($doc, $file);
```

additional information:

- the domain name is agriculture
- I have tried adding and removing agriculture\ in the `FTP_USERNAME`
- tried adding `\\` in front of the `FTP_HOST` IP address
- tried setting passive to both true and false
- changed port to 80
- server OS is Windows.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I was able to get the ftp driver to work as incorrect connection details were given to me initially. With the correct details, I was successful in storing the file in the correct folder on the file server. Requesting the question to be closed.

Comment: Have you checked that the host & port(is open) is reachable from the machine you're deploying on?

Comment: what did your firefox->network tab request/response logs read.

Comment: Instead of an FTP, you could also mount an NFS share of the other host. It behaves more like a local filesystem than FTP.

Comment: @Namoshek so share the folder on the file server, then map it to the local file system in Laravel?

Comment: @TaylorGoodallAU I will check if port 21 is open when next im back in work. the host is accessible definitely as I remote into it regularly during the day

Comment: @Ken_S NFS stands for _Network File System_, so you basically mount a remote directory at a local directory which will act as if you were using a local directory (with some limitations, although they should not be worse than FTP at all). It is basically a network file share you probably already know from your company workstations. You could for example mount a directory called `/data/app.example.com/share` located on the NFS server to your local `/data` directory on the `app.example.com` server. You then create a symlink from your Laravel `storage` directory to this `/data` directory.

Comment: @Namoshek I will discuss this with my network admin. it seems like a viable option. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The laravel documentation could give you a helping hand.

Otherwise you could go to `config/filesystems.php` and add your own custom storage path for both local and production

```
return [

    'default' => 'custom',
    'cloud' => 's3',
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => storage_path().'/app',
        ],

        'custom' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'root'   => '../path/to/your/new/storage/folder',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key'    => 'your-key',
            'secret' => 'your-secret',
            'region' => 'your-region',
            'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
        ],

        'rackspace' => [
            'driver'    => 'rackspace',
            'username'  => 'your-username',
            'key'       => 'your-key',
            'container' => 'your-container',
            'endpoint'  => 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/',
            'region'    => 'IAD',
        ],

    ],
];
```

Comment: Tried adding custom driver and got: Driver [custom] is not supported.

Comment: php artisan config:clear and php artisan config:cache   ------try those commands and run